# How do I add a Countdown Timer to my page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I am currently developing a Simon says type game using jQuery and JavaScript.

I have linked a fully copy of the game on Github

**Github download and unzip to see the game fully
https://github.com/Jamiex304/Simon_Says_Game_Demo**(Disabled Now)

I have reached a problem I want to add a timer that the player can see.

Currently the level will just go on till the user clicks the wrong button in the sequence.

**Some Basic info on the game:

The user will see a random sequence each level a new sequence is added with one more extra move.
Each time the user enters the right sequence they go to the next level
all info can be found in the attached JavaScript with comments**

**WHAT I WANT HELP ADDING**

**I just want to add a timer that starts at 10 seconds when the user clicks the start button.

Each time the enter the right sequence the timer starts again
when they reach 5 right sequences the timer adds 5 extra seconds.**

I have attached the JavaScript that handles the game events and there is a link to the full site.

Any help would be great.

JavaScript

```
var game={ //game object
    level: 1, //current level
    turn: 0, //current turn
    difficulty: 1, // user difficulty
    score: 0, //current score
    active: false, //whether a turn is active or not
    handler: false, // whether the click and sound handlers are active
    shape: '.shape', // cached string for the pad class
    genSequence: [], //array containing the generated/randomized pads
    plaSequence: [], //array containing the users pad selections
    
    init: function(){                   //initialises the game
        if(this.handler === false){     //checks to see if handlers are already active
            this.initPadHandler();      //if not activate them
        }
        this.newGame();             //reset the game defaults

    },

    initPadHandler: function(){

        that=this;

        $('.pad').on('mouseup',function(){

            if(that.active===true){

                var pad=parseInt($(this).data('pad'),10);
                    
                that.flash($(this),1,300, pad);

                that.logPlayerSequence(pad);

            }
        });

        this.handler=true;

    },

    newGame: function(){            //resets the game and generates a starts a new level

        this.level=1;
        this.score=0;
        this.newLevel();
        this.displayLevel();
        this.displayScore();

    },

    newLevel: function(){
        
        this.genSequence.length=0;
        this.plaSequence.length=0;
        this.pos=0;
        this.turn=0;
        this.active=true;
        
        this.randomizePad(this.level); //randomize pad with the correct amount of numbers for this level
        this.displaySequence(); //show the user the sequence

    },
    
    flash: function(element, times, speed, pad){ //function to make the pads appear to flash

        var that = this;                        //cache this

        if(times > 0){                          //make sure we are supposed to flash
            that.playSound(pad);                //play the corresponding pad sound
            element.stop().animate({opacity: '1'}, {        //animate the element to appear to flash
                duration: 50,
                complete: function(){
                element.stop().animate({opacity: '0.6'}, 200);
                }
            });                                             //end animation

        }

        if (times > 0) {                                    //call the flash function again until done the correct amount of times 
            setTimeout(function () {
                that.flash(element, times, speed, pad);
            }, speed);
            times -= 1;                     //times - 1 for each time it's called
        }
    },

    playSound: function(clip){              //plays the sound that corresponds to the pad chosen


        var sound= $('.sound'+clip)[0];
        console.log(sound);
        console.log($('.sound'+clip));
        sound.currentTime=0;                //resets audio position to the start of the clip
        sound.play();                       //play the sound


    },

    randomizePad: function(passes){         //generate random numbers and push them to the generated number array iterations determined by current level

        for(i=0;i<passes;i++){
            
            this.genSequence.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        }
    },

    logPlayerSequence: function(pad){       //log the player selected pad to user array and call the checker function

        this.plaSequence.push(pad);
        this.checkSequence(pad);
        
    
    },

    checkSequence: function(pad){           //checker function to test if the pad the user pressed was next in the sequence

        that=this;

        if(pad !== this.genSequence[this.turn]){    //if not correct 
                
                this.incorrectSequence();

            }else{                                  //if correct
                this.keepScore();                   //update the score
                this.turn++;                        //incrememnt the turn

            }

        if(this.turn === this.genSequence.length){  //if completed the whole sequence
            
            this.level++;                           //increment level, display it, disable the pads wait 1 second and then reset the game
            this.displayLevel();
            this.active=false;
            setTimeout(function(){
                that.newLevel();
            },1000);
        }
    },

    displaySequence: function(){                    //display the generated sequence to the user
        
        var that=this;

        $.each(this.genSequence, function(index, val) {     //iterate over each value in the generated array
            
            setTimeout(function(){
                
                that.flash($(that.shape+val),1,300,val);
            
            },500*index*that.difficulty);               // multiply timeout by how many items in the array so that they play sequentially and multiply by the difficulty modifier
        });
    },

    displayLevel: function(){                           //just display the current level on screen
        
        $('.level h2').text('Level: '+this.level);

    },

    displayScore: function(){                           //display current score on screen
        $('.score h2').text('Score: '+this.score);
    },

    keepScore: function(){                              //keep the score
        
        var multiplier=0;

        switch(this.difficulty)                         //choose points modifier based on difficulty
        {
            case '2':
                multiplier=1;
                break;
            
            case '1':
                multiplier=2;
                break;

            case '0.5':
                multiplier = 3;
                break;

            case '0.25':
                multiplier = 4;
                break;
        }

        this.score += (1 * multiplier);                 //work out the score

        this.displayScore();                            //display score on screen
    },

    incorrectSequence: function(){                      //if user makes a mistake

        var corPad = this.genSequence[this.turn],       //cache the pad number that should have been pressed
            
            that = this;
            this.active=false;
            this.displayLevel();
            this.displayScore();

        setTimeout(function(){                          //flash the pad 4 times that should have been pressed
            that.flash($(that.shape+corPad),4,300,corPad);
        },500);

        $('.start').show();                             //enable the start button again and allow difficulty selection again
        $('.difficulty').show();

    }

};
$(document).ready(function(){                           //document ready

    $('.start').on('mouseup', function(){               //initialise a game when the start button is clicked
        $(this).hide();
        game.difficulty = $('input[name=difficulty]:checked').val();
        $('.difficulty').hide();
        game.init();


    });

    
});
```

Comment: You're saying you want to increase the timer each level... so may i know ho do i level up in your game..? Or in other words, how do i play the game in your fiddle..?

Comment: @TJ Sorry at the moment the fiddle wont play the game problay, but how it works is, when u hit start 2 circles light up one after each other if you hit them in the right order u pass level 1, then the game shows you a new sequence this time with 3 circles lighting up and so on each time you enter the right sequence you go up a lvl and that is displayed below

Comment: How do you expect someone to write code accordingly if it doesn't work..?!!

Comment: @TJ I understand thats why i just put it up on my github and added the link to the question because i cant get it to run in fiddle, im sorry i am trying everything here

Comment: Oops, Nvm, I didn't notice the link to github...

Comment: @TJ do u think u can help with my problem now ?

Comment: That's a pretty fun game. I don't think it needs a timer though. Level 8 is pretty damn impossible, time isn't the issue.

Comment: @Rudie the timer will lead into future functions thats why i want to add it now rather than later, thats the reason i am trying to get this done fast so i can move on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think i've managed to do it the way you want it, here is full js:

(I've commented the parts i've added)

```
var game={ //game object
    level: 1, //current level
    turn: 0, //current turn
    difficulty: 1, // user difficulty
    score: 0, //current score
    active: false, //whether a turn is active or not
    handler: false, // whether the click and sound handlers are active
    shape: '.shape', // cached string for the pad class
    genSequence: [], //array containing the generated/randomized pads
    plaSequence: [], //array containing the users pad selections

    init: function(){                   //initialises the game
        if(this.handler === false){     //checks to see if handlers are already active
            this.initPadHandler();      //if not activate them
        }
        this.newGame();             //reset the game defaults

    },

    initPadHandler: function(){

        that=this;

        $('.pad').on('mouseup',function(){

            if(that.active===true){

                var pad=parseInt($(this).data('pad'),10);

                that.flash($(this),1,300, pad);

                that.logPlayerSequence(pad);

            }
        });

        this.handler=true;

    },

    newGame: function(){            //resets the game and generates a starts a new level

        this.level=1;
        this.score=0;
        this.newLevel();
        this.displayLevel();
        this.displayScore();

        //initialize timer to 10 seconds
        this.timer = 10;  

    },

    newLevel: function(){

        this.genSequence.length=0;
        this.plaSequence.length=0;
        this.pos=0;
        this.turn=0;
        this.active=true;

        this.randomizePad(this.level); //randomize pad with the correct amount of numbers for this level
        this.displaySequence(); //show the user the sequence
    },

    flash: function(element, times, speed, pad){ //function to make the pads appear to flash

        var that = this;                        //cache this

        if(times > 0){                          //make sure we are supposed to flash
            that.playSound(pad);                //play the corresponding pad sound
            element.stop().animate({opacity: '1'}, {        //animate the element to appear to flash
                duration: 50,
                complete: function(){
                element.stop().animate({opacity: '0.6'}, 200);
                }
            });                                             //end animation

        }

        if (times > 0) {                                    //call the flash function again until done the correct amount of times 
            setTimeout(function () {
                that.flash(element, times, speed, pad);
            }, speed);
            times -= 1;                     //times - 1 for each time it's called
        }
    },

    playSound: function(clip){              //plays the sound that corresponds to the pad chosen


        var sound= $('.sound'+clip)[0];
        console.log(sound);
        console.log($('.sound'+clip));
        sound.currentTime=0;                //resets audio position to the start of the clip
        sound.play();                       //play the sound


    },

    randomizePad: function(passes){         //generate random numbers and push them to the generated number array iterations determined by current level

        for(i=0;i<passes;i++){

            this.genSequence.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        }
    },

    logPlayerSequence: function(pad){       //log the player selected pad to user array and call the checker function

        this.plaSequence.push(pad);
        this.checkSequence(pad);


    },

    checkSequence: function(pad){           //checker function to test if the pad the user pressed was next in the sequence

        that=this;

        if(pad !== this.genSequence[this.turn]){    //if not correct 

                this.incorrectSequence();

            }else{                                  //if correct
                this.keepScore();                   //update the score
                this.turn++;                        //incrememnt the turn

            }

        if(this.turn === this.genSequence.length){  //if completed the whole sequence

            this.level++;                           //increment level, display it, disable the pads wait 1 second and then reset the game
            this.displayLevel();
            this.active=false;

            // Stop counting when sequence is correct to avoid time running out before starting next level
            clearInterval(this.timerInterval);

            //Add 5 seconds each 5th level
            this.timer = 10 + 5 * Math.floor(this.level / 5);

            //Update timerdisplay to show fulltime while displaying next level sequence
            $(".Timer p").html(this.timer);

            setTimeout(function(){
                that.newLevel();
            },1000);
        }
    },

    // Countdown and update timer, call incorrectsequence when time's up
    countDown: function(){ 
        this.timer -= 0.1;
        $(".Timer p").html(this.timer.toFixed(1));   // Display 9.0 instad of 9
        if(this.timer < 0.1){
            this.incorrectSequence();
        }
    },

    displaySequence: function(){                    //display the generated sequence to the user

        var that=this;

        var timerCount = 0;

        $.each(this.genSequence, function(index, val) {     //iterate over each value in the generated array
            timerCount = index;
            setTimeout(function(){

                that.flash($(that.shape+val),1,300,val);

            },500*index*that.difficulty);               // multiply timeout by how many items in the array so that they play sequentially and multiply by the difficulty modifier
        });

        // Wait to start timer until full sequence is displayed
        setTimeout(function(){ that.timerInterval = setInterval(function(){that.countDown()}, 100)}, 500*timerCount*that.difficulty);
    },

    displayLevel: function(){                           //just display the current level on screen

        $('.level h2').text('Level: '+this.level);

    },

    displayScore: function(){                           //display current score on screen
        $('.score h2').text('Score: '+this.score);
    },

    keepScore: function(){                              //keep the score

        var multiplier=0;

        switch(this.difficulty)                         //choose points modifier based on difficulty
        {
            case '2':
                multiplier=1;
                break;

            case '1':
                multiplier=2;
                break;

            case '0.5':
                multiplier = 3;
                break;

            case '0.25':
                multiplier = 4;
                break;
        }

        this.score += (1 * multiplier);                 //work out the score

        this.displayScore();                            //display score on screen
    },

    incorrectSequence: function(){                      //if user makes a mistake

        //Stop counting down timer and display start message
        clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
        $(".Timer p").html("Get Ready your time starts when you click start");

        var corPad = this.genSequence[this.turn],       //cache the pad number that should have been pressed

            that = this;
            this.active=false;
            this.displayLevel();
            this.displayScore();

        setTimeout(function(){                          //flash the pad 4 times that should have been pressed
            that.flash($(that.shape+corPad),4,300,corPad);
        },500);

        $('.start').show();                             //enable the start button again and allow difficulty selection again
        $('.difficulty').show();

    }

};
$(document).ready(function(){                           //document ready

    $('.start').on('mouseup', function(){               //initialise a game when the start button is clicked
        $(this).hide();
        game.difficulty = $('input[name=difficulty]:checked').val();
        $('.difficulty').hide();
        game.init();


    });


});
```

You can check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uusL7hch/embedded/result/) (sounds disabled in fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really say specifically what you want other than a timer, but based off your markup is something like this what you're looking for?

[Here is your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3u01t9vo/1/)

```js
var $timer = $('.Timer'),
    $timerTitle = $('.TimerTitle'),
    $start = $('.start'),
    $increment = $('.increment'),
    maxDuration = 10,
    defaultDuration = 10,
    count = 0,
    $gameCount = $('#gameCount');
    

$timerTitle.text("Get ready! You have " + maxDuration + " seconds!");

$start.on('click', function()
{
    getDuration();
    return false;
});

function getDuration()
{
    $start.prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        var duration = $timer.data('duration');
        if(duration === undefined || duration < 0)
            duration = maxDuration;
        
        $timer.text(duration);
        $timer.data('duration', --duration);
        
        if(duration > -1)
        {
            if(duration < 5)
            {
                if(duration % 2 == 0)
                {
                    $timer.css({'background-color':'blue', 'color':'white'});
                }
                else
                {
                    $timer.css({'background-color':'transparent', 'color':'black'});
                }
            }
            getDuration();
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
            $gameCount.text("Current game count: " + count);
            if(count % 5 == 0)
                defaultDuration += 5;
            
            maxDuration = defaultDuration;
            $timer.css({'background-color':'transparent', 'color':'black'});
            $timer.text('');
            $timerTitle.text("Get ready! You have " + maxDuration + " seconds!");
            $start.prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align='center'>
<div class="TimerTitle"></div>
<div class="Timer"></div>
<br />
<button class="start">start</button>
<div id='gameCount'>Current game count: 0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: again this is some what helpful but i dont know how i am not being specife in what i am asking for help with. I have a game that i want to add a timer to that counts down when the user clicks start and each time they finish a level it starts again at 10 and after 5 levels in go's up by 5 seconds, any help you can offer would be great thanks again

Comment: @Jamiex304 Check out the updated fiddle, it will auto increment the timer after 5 levels

Comment: Again this is close to what i want but as i have said above i need it to reset to 10 each new level in the game currently your example just keeps counting down to 0, i have updated the question with all the info. but thank you for taking the time to help

Comment: I dont suppose u have any other ideas about how to make it stop counting down to 0 rather than refresh after each lvl in the game ?

Comment: Sorry again but i need help tieing it in with my javascript code above so the time stops each time the player go's up a level

Comment: @Jamiex304 I updated my fiddle so that it is using your script with a timer.  I don't have the css or anything, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Jamiex304 Okay, we might have it this time, I now see exactly what you were going for.  Having a fiddle helps people understand what exactly you're trying to do.  I updated your fiddle so that it has the timer and updated the levels and what not.  It's linked in the answer.

Comment: We are nearly there only problem is the timer does not reset to 10 when the user enters the right sequence the fiddle i have up is not working right so u cant play the game probably but, if the user enters the right sequence they go to level 2 and the timer starts at 10 again, i don't want the timer to go to the next level, the only reason the timer should hit 10 is if the user runs out of time or does not enter the sequence fast enough but thanks for still trying to help

Comment: i have added a link to my github where u can download and run the game to see it run problay it might help if u can see it work and what i mean thanks again for all the help

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unconventional (it doesn't count down, but up), but how's this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/nrp3e269/

The magic is `tick()` which triggers 60/s:

```
var tickStart = 0;
function tick() {
    var tickSpent = (Date.now() - tickStart) / 1000,
        timeLeft = startTimeLeft - tickSpent;
    tl.textContent = Math.round(timeLeft * 10) / 10;
    if ( timeLeft > 0 ) {
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }
    else {
        document.body.classList.add('gameover');
    }
}
```

The start button kicks off the count:

```
tickStart = Date.now();
tick();
```

The move button adds time to the count:

```
if ( ++moves % 5 == 0 ) {
    startTimeLeft += 5;
}
else {
    startTimeLeft += 1;
}
```

It's just a proof of concept. You're gonna have to do the bulk. First thing would be to make it a nice CountDown object with methods and local properties instead of globals.

```
CountDown.startTimeLeft
CountDown.tickStart
CountDown.tick()
CountDown.start()
CountDown.finish()
CountDown.addTime()
```

To separate your app logic from the ticker.

Comment: im sorry but this just left me completely lost the problem i am having is linking the timer with the game so each time the user completes a level i would need it to start again u can see how the game runs from the github link, but thanks anyway

Comment: Like I said: you'll need to do the bulk. We can help you with timer logic,  but you have to write the game.

Comment: thats why i am here i have found multiple examples of timers in all forms the problem i am having is making the timer interact with my game thats the problem, but thanks again

Comment: Didn't try anything... What's your specific issue, so we can help you with that, so you can apply it to the game?

Comment: I find it very hard to believe you made this game (pretty advanced stuff), but don't know how to add a simple timer...

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might work?

```
var n = 100;
setTimeout(countDown,1000);

function countDown(){
   n--;
   if(n > 0){
      setTimeout(countDown,1000);
   }
   $(".timer").html(n);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gfdq8krd/

Comment: this is close to what i want but i dont want the timer to start til the user starts the game and second if it reaches zero i want the game to end

Answer (score -2):

If i understand you just want to countdown ? from 10 sec and so on ?
than this script will help you i think

```
<script>

<!-- 
//change below target URL to your own OTHERWISE DELETE
// this link will redirect you to the main page or the page you want
var targetURL="example.com" 
//change the second to start counting down from 
var countdownfrom=10

var currentsecond=document.redirect.redirect2.value=countdownfrom+1 
function countredirect(){ 
if (currentsecond!=1){ 
currentsecond-=1 
document.redirect.redirect2.value=currentsecond 
} 
else{ 
window.location=targetURL 
return 
} 
setTimeout("countredirect()",1000) 
}

countredirect() 
//--> 
</script>
```

Comment: i can see what you are trying to show me but, one it doesnt display the countdown for the user and I have tried it but got no reset, also i keep getting the error, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'redirect2' of undefined